# What are the first 4 Strings received on telnet connection?

Tags: tcp, arrays, telnet

I'm emulating a telnet server for my application. When I connect to my app via telnet(just using putty to connect locally) I always receive these 4 sequences on initial connect.

```
    ByteString(-1, -5, 31, -1, -5, 32, -1, -5, 24, -1, -5, 39, -1, -3, 1, -1, -5, 3, -1, -3, 3),
    ByteString(-1, -2, 31, -1, -2, 32, -1, -2, 24, -1, -2, 39, -1, -4, 1),
    ByteString(-1, -5, 36),
    ByteString(-1, -2, 36)
```

I figured, the connection is established successfully if I return these back to client. But I'd rather know what these are and how and if I should handle them differently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are Telnet command sequences.

```
-1 -5 31 = IAC WILL NAWS
-1 -5 32 = IAC WILL TERMINAL-SPEED
-1 -5 24 = IAC WILL TERMINAL-TYPE
-1 -5 39 = IAC WILL NEW-ENVIRON
-1 -3 1  = IAC DO   ECHO
-1 -5 3  = IAC WILL SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD
-1 -3 3  = IAC DO   SUPPRESS-GO-AHEAD
-1 -2 31 = IAC DONT NAWS
-1 -2 32 = IAC DONT TERMINAL-SPEED
-1 -2 24 = IAC DONT TERMINAL-TYPE
-1 -2 39 = IAC DONT NEW-ENVIRON
-1 -4 1  = IAC WONT ECHO
-1 -5 36 = IAC WILL ENVIRON
-1 -2 36 = IAC DONT ENVIRON
```

Read [RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), [RFC 855](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc855) and other [related RFCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Related_RFCs) that define the Telnet protocol and its [various options](http://www.iana.org/assignments/telnet-options/telnet-options.xhtml) (there are a lot of them).

Comment: i actually stumbled upon RFC 854 but could not find most of what you translated in this post, do you use some sort of software to translate these? or did you just looked up all those in a minute? :)

Comment: I translated them manually, using the links I provided in my answer (and a decimal/hex calculator). And it took a little longer than 1 minute, more like 10 minutes, but I wrote this using a tablet, it would have been faster on a PC :-)